# :GCheckout, :checkhealth in neovim spits out gibberish next to branch name

Tags: git, neovim

I've plugged [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) in my [init.vim](https://github.com/Nishant-Pall/Neovim-Config/blob/ubuntu/init.vim). I have binded my `:GCheckout` to `<leader>gc`, and for the config I only have two branches, main and ubuntu. but when I run the above command this is what I get inside the window that pops up.

[image]

If I try to delete the branch using `<C-d>`, this is what I get. This seems to be problem with the fish but I'm not sure how it is messing up as my `ls -l /bin/sh` gives me `/bin/sh -> dash` which I guess means that my default shell isn't fish.

[image]

I tried doing `:checkhealth` and found something similar which looks like this

[image]

I couldn't find any solution so this is the last resort, hoping to get some help.

Comment: What terminal are you using? Looks like your terminal does not support some escape sequences. What is the value of TERM enviornment variable? What system are you using? What is in the `## terminal` section in `:checkhealth` output? `binded my :GCheckout` What does `GCheckout` do? I do not see it in https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/46404ad9376f38a0bf8421310373aefbc92e190d/doc/fugitive.txt . And - this is offtopic for stackoverflow. Ask this question on vim.stackexchange

Comment: It's the normal gnome-terminal from Ubuntu 20.04, TERM variable throws out `xterm-256color`. I'm on Lenovo IP 330-s with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The `## terminal` is 
```4 ## terminal
  3   - INFO: key_backspace (kbs) terminfo entry: key_backspace=\177
  2   - INFO: key_dc (kdch1) terminfo entry: key_dc=\E[3~
  1   - INFO: $VTE_VERSION='6003'
47    - INFO: $COLORTERM='truecolor'
```
`GCheckout` basically shows all the branches in the repository, although I found out it's completely unrelated to the cause. I am using fish shell perhaps that can lead to this issue?